# Is Blade Dancer a constant encounter in a Search Point?

Tags: tales-of-the-abyss

While making my way to capital of Malkuth in order to stop the war i came across a Search Point along the way, when i went to examine it i got into a battle with Blade Dancer which i had previously defeated in Coral Castle.

I ended up having to flee after getting my party but myself wiped out and no way to resurrect them. i went to examine the search point again and i fought Blade Dancer again, this time however i just fled.

I am wondering, is Blade Dancer a Is Blade Dancer a constant encounter in this Search Point or will he no longer appear if i defeat him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade Dancer is a 3-fight sidequest that grants a pretty nice sword for Luke at the end (765 Attack Power). See the [wiki](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_Dancer). You have to fight the one at this point for the last one to appear (if it's not the third one already).